# Is there any Regex optimizer written in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a Java program which can generate a sequence of symbols, like `"abcdbcdefbcdbcdefg"`. What I need is Regex optimizer, which can result `"a((bcd){2}ef){2}g"`.

As the input may contain unicodes, like `"a\u0063\u0063\bbd"`, I prefer a Java version.

The reason I want to get a "shorter" expression is for saving space/memory. The sequence of symbols here could be very long.

In general, to find the "shortest" optimized regex is hard. So, here, I don't need ones that guarantee the "shortest" criteria.

Comment: You're basically looking to compress your input string and output a format that looks like regex?

Comment: Please define 'regex optimizer'.

Comment: Guessing your needs from your example, I suggest the blazingly fast `return ".*";`

Comment: @Blender Yes, exactly. If you think the title is not suitable, I can change.

Comment: @bdares Could you explain more? what does return ".*" mean?

Comment: Why do you want to compress (you call it 'optimized') the regex? Who cares? The regex won't run any faster, in fact it may run more slowly when compressed.

Comment: Moreover, if you're just selecting the whole string why use regex in the first place?

Comment: A regex describes a possibly infinitely large set of strings.  For any given string, there are an infinite number of regexes that fit that string.  Your question is meaningless without some criteria for selecting a particular regex for a particular string.

Comment: There is no regex optimizer. Thats because the compiler doesen't know what you have in mind. The minute you venture into something that is optional, all bets are off.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what he's really asking for is a small regex that encodes a _finite_ set of strings. This is a very solvable and interesting problem.

Comment: Its probably more solvabable if its hand rolled using pointers and string api's, no?

Comment: Yes I think the title is not suitable, please change.

Answer (score 5):

I've got a nasty feeling that the problem of creating the shortest regex that matches a given input string or set of strings is going to be computationally "difficult".  (There are parallels with the problem of computing Kolmogorov Complexity ...)

It is also worth noting that the optimal regex for `abcdbcdefbcdbcdefg` in terms of matching speed is likely to be `abcdbcdefbcdbcdefg`.  Adding repeating groups may make the regex string shorter, but it won't make the regex faster.  In fact, it is likely to be slower unless the regex engine unrolls the repeating groups.

> The reason that I need this is due to the space/memory limits.

Do you have clear evidence that you *need* to do this?

I suspect that you won't save a worthwhile amount of space by doing this ... unless the input strings are really long.  (And if they are long, then you'll get better results using a regular text compression algorithm to compress the strings.)

Comment: I totally agree with you. The reason that I need this is due to the space/memory limits.

Comment: All equivalent regular expressions should compile to the same NFA and DFA but it is impossible to tell whether this has anything to do with his actual need.

Comment: It seems to be be equivalent to the [smallest grammar problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_grammar_problem) for regular languages.

Answer (score 2):

**Regular expressions are not a substitute for compression**

Don't use a regular expression to represent a string constant. Regular expressions are designed to be used to match one of many strings. That's not what you're doing.

Comment: He is trying to represent a _set_ of strings.  A regex is a fine way to do that.

Comment: @Gene: His example suggests he is trying to represent a single string.

Comment: I believe a factored set of strings that are constants exactly. Using pointers and string api's gets you to the difference, from there its easy. There is so much overhead in regex, its not useful on finite sets!

Comment: @Gene - and besides, text compression works fine on sets of strings too, provided that you join the strings together before compression.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to find a small regex to encode a *finite* set of input strings.  If so, you haven't chosen the best possible subject line.

I can't give you an existing program, but I can tell you how to approach writing one.

There is no canonical minimum regex form and [determining the true minimum size regex is NP hard](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/is-finding-the-minimum-regular-expression-an-np-complete-problem).  Certainly your sets are finite, so this may be a simpler problem.  I'll have to think about it.

But a good heuristic algorithm would be:

1. Construct a trivial non-deterministic finite automaton (NFA) that accepts all your strings.
2. Convert the NFA to a deterministic finite automaton (DFA) with the subset construction.
3. Minimize the DFA with the standard algorithm.
4. Use the [construction from the proof of Kleene's theorem](http://neumannhaus.com/christoph/papers/2005-03-16.DFA_to_RegEx.pdf) to get to a regex.

Note that step 3 *does* give you a unique minimum DFA. That would probably be the best way to encode your string sets.

Comment: If at all variable repetition, the only approach is human interpretation given the constructs of regex. I interpret this to be at about %100 of the time, otherwise a regex is not needed.

Comment: Your solution is an option. The problem is that the strings are really long. I don't want to store all the strings directly into the files.